# cakephp facebook helper?

Tags: facebook, cakephp

Has anyone adapted the facebook api into a cake helper class? I'm making a facebook application in cake and need to be able to use all the class functions and stuff and don't want to spend ages integrating it myself if someone has already done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aforementioned CakePhp-Facebook-plugin seems very good and I would definitely go with it if it fits your needs. In my case, I needed something much simpler and lightweight only for the OAuth part. So I simply downloaded the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php), put it in my vendors directory, and then import it from my controller like so:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook', array('file' => 'Facebook.php'));
```

and created whatever function I needed based on Facebook's examples:

```
public function facebook() {
    $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'your_app_id', 'secret' =>'your_app_secret', 'cookie' => true));
    $session = $facebook->getSession();
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin

I have not personally used this, but I have heard good things.

Comment: it have problems with Cakephp 2